# Is it possible to print ID properly straight from the browser?

Tags: browser, printing

I wanted to design a simple ID printing software for my company, where I would load a database of entries and generate HTML/php output using a Background image as template, and css/html positioned text for the details and image.

I plan to use it on my own browser, therefore i have full control over the browser print settings..

I actually tried to do a basic HTML page emulating the output and i just can't get it to print right on our Datacard ID Printer (prints directly to PVC ID cards) ..

though i've set the browser (firefox) margins to zero and the print settings to scale , it's either i get a small margin left and top side of the card, or the printer prints out 2 cards (the id spans through 2 or more pages)

Is there ever a way, perhaps the proper browser setting , or registry hack or something that can get my html page to print right on a standard ID size output?

Regards